# What’s the deal with Super Saiyan God in the English anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

I’m currently watching the American Dragonball Super dub on Toonami and I noticed Goku and Vegeta power up to Super Saiyan Blue but don’t use Super Saiyan God. In the Japanese anime and manga, the Super Saiyan God is a useable transformation separate from Blue and Goku used it  to fight Hit and to overpower Trunks and to fight the female Saiyans. Why are they skipping it here in America?

Comment: Could you add some references to what episodes / times you are talking about?  It's kinda hard to figure out what you are talking about otherwise.

Comment: Super saiyan God is red hair. You're saying they transformed to god but still used the term blue?

Answer (score 2):

The Super Saiyan Blue Transformation is referred to as SSGSS which is (Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan). This is a transformation attained by combining the powers of a God with the Super Saiyan transformation.

This transformation is significantly stronger than the Super Saiyan God transformation. The only difference is, it consumes more stamina and is more physically straining on the body. Since the transformation is stronger, Goku and Vegeta use this transformation over Super Saiyan God.

Please note that the manga and the anime have many differences. Goku never uses the Super Saiyan God transformation against Hit in the anime. He does not use Super Saiyan Blue stacked with Kaioken against Hit in the manga. However, the Dragon Ball Super Dub isn't really different from the main series. In the anime, Vegeta never uses this transformation while Goku does (Note: In the manga, Vegeta does use the transformation). Goku does make use of the Super Saiyan God transformation later in the series after using it against Beerus.

## Spoilers Anime

> - Goku uses the Super Saiyan God transformation initially in the tournament of Power while helping Hit fight Dyspo and Kunshi on account of saving stamina and being stronger than the regular Super Saiyan transformations.
> - He uses it again during his first fight with Jiren.
> - The transformation is used by Goku during his fight with Caulifla and Kale and also against Base Kefla until he transforms.
> - He finally uses this transformation against Anilaza, before transforming to Super Saiyan Blue for his final attack.